# PowerBuilder, DataWindow conditional formatting

Tags: powerbuilder

I have DataWindow with 'name' and 'code'. Also in the SELECT for this DW, I have PM.
If PM is null, then I want name to be bold.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should do the following steps:

1. Open the datawindow
2. Select the "name" column
3. Click on the "Font" tabpage (at the right)
4. Right of the Bold checkbox there is a small square (click on it, and the Expression popup will appear)
5. Paste this:

   if( IsNull(PM), 700, 0)

The column values will be bold as you need.

Br. Gábor

Comment: You're welcome. Here are some additional values for font weigth you can use:

Values are:

100—Thin

200—Extra light

300—Light

400—Normal

500—Medium

600—Semibold 

700—Bold 

800—Extrabold 

900—Heavy 

 Most commonly used values 
The most commonly used values are 400 (Normal) and 700 (Bold).